# Loop through a column and vstack to a new single column using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of strings, example below. Each string is a delimited combinations of texts. Each row has different number of texts. I want to create a single column with one text per row based on this column.

FROM:

```
a;b
x;y;z
p;q;r;s;t
```

TO:

```
a
b
x
y
z
p
q
r
s
t
```

**How do I achieve this using a single formula?**

I tried `TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE, data),";"))`
However, this fails because the TEXTJOIN part results in more than 32767 characters.

I also tried building a 2D array of mxn where m=no. of rows in the original data and n=no. of texts. However, the MAKEARRAY still results in a single column. Had it worked, I would have used TOCOL or something similar to convert to a single column.

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COLUMNS(MAX(num_of_texts_in_each_row)), LAMBDA(r,c, LET(
drow, INDEX(data,r,1),
splits, TEXTSPLIT(drow,";"),
INDEX(splits,,c)
)))
```

Comment: Why is COLUMNS in there?

Comment: thank you!! that was an error and it solved the entire problem when i removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach would be by using REDUCE:

`=DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,,";")))),1)`

[image]

REDUCE behaves like a BYROW, where the VSTACK stacks the spilled result per row on top of eachother after the full spill value.
As it starts at 0, we use DROP the first value to get the desired result.

We could also avoid DROP, but that makes the formula more complicated and longer, but for reference:
`=REDUCE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,";"),A2:A3,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,,";"))))`

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks! I was hoping that REDUCE would do it but my Excel version just received REDUCE a few days ago, haven't experienced it enough.

Comment: It's very useful. See what happens if you change VSTACK to HSTACK and wrap it in IFERROR: `=IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(A1,A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,";")))),1),"")`

Comment: Great stuff. I'm starting to think that `REDUCE` is fast-becoming the new function of choice: it can mimic, for example, `BYROW`, as you have shown here, and, more importantly, its in-built pseudo-recursive nature can also give it a distinctive edge over the other new functions in many situations.

Comment: Having said that, I have to say that I'm a little disappointed in MS for the fact that functions such as `TEXTSPLIT` are not able to generate an array of returns.

Comment: I thought the same, but I reckon that's because TEXTSPLIT has two conditions for splitting: by row and/or by column. That way a 2D array would be generated by the formula itself. That's probably why. I would've expected it to work in combination with BYROW if you where to spill the textsplit result horizontally by row, but in that case REDUCE seems to outsmart BYROW

Comment: Good point re `TEXTSPLIT`s two delimiter arguments. Perhaps MS could have made this optional, i.e. you can specify a 1D version of the function, such that it will generate an array of returns when passed a range of more than one cell.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:A3,
    clm,MAX(BYROW(rng,LAMBDA(a,COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(a,";"))))),
    TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(rng),clm,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A1:A3,a),";"),b))),3))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i tried but made a minor mistake.